# yum: the same packages in two repositories, force to install the package from a different repo

Tags: yum, repository

I am developing a PostgresDB plugin. The plugin is being run in Postgres in Centos 6.3. To be able to compile my project, I had to install some of the libraries from the epel repository and some from the rpmforge. Interestengly enough some of the packages are duplicated in both repositories, e.g.,:

```
# yum whatprovides postgis

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * Webmin: download.webmin.com
 * base: mirror2.hs-esslingen.de
 * epel: mirror.awanti.com
 * extras: mirror2.hs-esslingen.de
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.netcologne.de
postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64 : Geographic Information Systems Extensions to
                           : PostgreSQL
Repo        : epel
Matched from:



postgis-1.3.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64 : Geographic Information Systems Extensions to
                              : PostgreSQL
Repo        : rpmforge
Matched from:
```

Now my project compiles, but does not link with missing references:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/postgis-1.5.so: undefined reference to `accumArrayResult'
/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/postgis-1.5.so: undefined reference to `TupleDescGetAttInMetadata'
/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/postgis-1.5.so: undefined reference to `repalloc'
/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/postgis-1.5.so: undefined reference to `SPI_exec'
/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/postgis-1.5.so: undefined reference to `init_MultiFuncCall'
```

which most probably means, that some packages got mixed up: some are install from one repo, and some from the other.

Questions: (i) how can I tell yum to install the package from one repo and then reinstall from the other (to see whether the linking errors would go away); (ii) how can I see what packages on the system are installed from one repo and what from the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yum list installed` will tell you from what repo a given package was installed, e.g.:

```
bonnie++.x86_64                     1.96-2.el6                  @epel/6.2
```

To select which variant to install, just use the exact name of the variant you want to install from your `whatprovides` list:

```
yum install postgis-1.3.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64
```

For more info, see the `specify package names` section of `man yum`.

Answer (score 9):

To install a package from one, exclude the package(s) in the /etc/yum.repos.d/epel or /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge files.

exclude= < packagename >

added at the end, you can add multiple lines if you want.

The packages installed should be listed in /var/log/yum.log

Comment: good point and a useful post